# Has André Breton's "The Language of Stones" been published in English translation?

Tags: art

Issue 3 of the French-language journal *Le Surréalisme Même*, published in 1957, contains the article "Langue des Pierres" ("Language of Stones"), by André Breton. Has this article ever been published in English translation?

Comment: You might want to document the searches you've already done to prevent duplication of effort.

Comment: This might be better suited to [Literature SE](https://literature.stackexchange.com)

Comment: The wikipedia page on Andre Breton in English mentions which of his major works are available in English (maybe half of them). There is a French edition of his complete works but it appears to be not available in Englsih. Neither the English nor the French wikipedia mention this article anywhere as part of his work, so it seems to be considered minor. This strongly suggests to me that this article was never published as an English translation, you probably will have to get in French.